# SQL Managment Studio 2008 R2 dual monitor support?

Tags: sql

I have a question. If it is possible to achieve I may just jump with joy.

As many of you undoubtedly already know, Visual Studio 2010 has support that allows you to drag and position your open files within a project. For example you have Page.aspx and Page.aspx.cs open. You can drag the tab and position it around. You can dock it in parts of visual studion, but you can also allow it to float as a separate window.

I am wondering. Can the same thing be done with Microsoft SQL Managment Studio 2008 R2? This would be extremely useful when I need to view a stored procedure or table and work on another stored procedure or table. I would love to be able to somehow drag out the tab to my second monitor.

If there isn't any built in functionality for this, is there any third party add-ons available? If not, does anybody have any tricks that they use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SQL Server 2012 (code-named "Denali", due by the end of 2011) will be shipping with a new SQL Server Management Studio, based on Visual Studio 2010, which will feature multi-monitor support.

See: [SQL SERVER – 2012 – Multi-Monitor SSMS Windows](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/24/sql-server-2011-multi-monitor-ssms-windows/)

[image]

With earlier versions of SQL Server Management Studio (based on VS2005/2008), you cannot do this, unfortunately.

You'll have to be patient until SQL Server 2012 ships... or you can [download the CTP1 test release](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/future-editions.aspx) to get an early feeling of what it'll be like...

Comment: ahh thank you. Unfortunately I could try it out at home. But I do not interact with dbs often at all in my side projects. My work is configured for 2008 R2. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for the same thing. After reading this answer, I was not impressed at all. I just thought.."what if...?"

Create a new vertical group, max sure SSMS is not maximized. Extend the window to the other monitor. Adjust the vertical groups. Now you have them on both screens. It works like a charm my friend. (;

Comment: +1 Very fiddly, but a reasonably good solution for the rare occasions I need this kind of setup.

Comment: It sure is better than nothing. Glad it helped someone other than myself.